# How can I loop over a complete Python script with minimal code changes?

Tags: python, loops, preprocessor

**Disclaimer**: I am a scientist, not a developer. I prefer readable and maintainable code, but I code to produce results, not code.

I often find myself in a situation to run a short script many times to test out the influence of one or more parameters. Very often, it is not easy to know beforehand which parameters I will be varying.

Let's say I have this pseudocode:

```
INPUT_FILE = "data.csv"
N_COMP = 7
MIN_SIZE = 35
MAX_SIZE = 70
OUTPUT_FILE = f"plot_{N_COMP}.pdf"

data = read(INPUT_FILE)
results = process(data, N_COMP)
figure = plot(results, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE)
store(figure, OUTPUT_FILE)
```

Now, I'd like to try the impact of various values of `N_COMP`. I could add a loop over most of the script:

```
INPUT_FILE = "data.csv"
# N_COMP = 7
MIN_SIZE = 35
MAX_SIZE = 70

for N_COMP in (3, 5, 7, 9, 11):
  OUTPUT_FILE = f"plot_{N_COMP}.pdf"
  
  data = read(INPUT_FILE)
  results = process(data, N_COMP)
  figure = plot(results, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE)
  store(figure, OUTPUT_FILE)
```

But this gets messy as soon as I want to go through several variables (maybe even at once), not even mentioning what `black` will do to my close-to-88-character lines each time I indent by one additional level.

I could also wrap the loop body in a function:

```
INPUT_FILE = "data.csv"
MIN_SIZE = 35
MAX_SIZE = 70

def pipeline(N_COMP):
  OUTPUT_FILE = f"plot_{N_COMP}.pdf"

  data = read(INPUT_FILE)
  results = process(data, N_COMP)
  figure = plot(results, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE)
  store(figure, OUTPUT_FILE)

for N_COMP in (3, 5, 7, 9, 11):
  pipeline(N_COMP)
```

However, the indentation problem remains, and now each time want to add an additional parameter that I potentially want to loop over, I have to add it in three places instead of only one. And finally, the definition of the parameters is in different places in the code. (I could make it four instead of three by defining the tuple at the top and reusing it in the loop.)

So what I am looking for is a solution like this:

```
from autoloop import looptuple

INPUT_FILE = "data.csv"
N_COMP = looptuple(3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
MIN_SIZE = 35
MAX_SIZE = 70
OUTPUT_FILE = f"plot_{N_COMP}.pdf"

data = read(INPUT_FILE)
results = process(data, N_COMP)
figure = plot(results, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE)
store(figure, OUTPUT_FILE)
```

And that should do what the code samples above do, with one changed line per parameter and no additional indentation. I would be OK with using a different command line to call this script, but that should be a generic way agnostic of parameters or parameter values to loop over.

(How) is this possible?

Comment: i may not have understood you question correctly but you can loop over a range like this: for i in range(0, 12, 2) where the third parameter specifies the step which basically means that it will return values of 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10

Comment: @Matiiss you are absolutely correct, and you did not understand my question correctly ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no internal way to "autoloop" like that, especially when your code is not wrapped into a function and uses global variables.

## Using environment variables

The lowest-impact change would probably be to use an environment variable for the parameter(s) you want to change, e.g.

```
import os

INPUT_FILE = "data.csv"
N_COMP = int(os.environ.get("N_COMP", 7))
MIN_SIZE = 35
MAX_SIZE = 70
OUTPUT_FILE = f"plot_{N_COMP}.pdf"
# ...
```

Then you can run the script (assuming an UNIX-y shell) with

```
env N_COMP=16 python my_script.py
```

and maybe automate that, e.g.

```
for n_comp in 3 5 7 9 11 42; do 
  env N_COMP=$n_comp python my_script.py
done
```

## Using a runner function

If the body of the script is something like above, then to automate it internally, the entry point must be wrapped in a function, e.g.

```
def run_experiment():
    data = read(INPUT_FILE)
    results = process(data, N_COMP)
    figure = plot(results, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE)
    store(figure, OUTPUT_FILE)
```

After that, you can add a runner function; with some gentle misuses of `globals()` we can make this quite dynamic:

```
import itertools

# Defaults (will be overwritten)
N_COMP = 3
N_KITTENS = 8


def run_experiment():
    print("N_COMP * N_KITTENS:", N_COMP * N_KITTENS)


def run_experiments():
    experiments = {
        "N_COMP": (1, 3, 5, 7),
        "N_KITTENS": (3, 9, 42, 64),
    }
    keys, values = zip(*experiments.items())
    for value_combo in itertools.product(*values):
        experiment_values = dict(zip(keys, value_combo))
        # You should add dependent values such as OUTPUT_FILE here
        print("Running:", experiment_values)
        globals().update(experiment_values)
        run_experiment()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_experiments()
```

Comment: This is basically the "loop over function" solution, just using an external loop to solve the indentation issue. It does not solve the maintenance problem of having to add a variable in several places (and makes it even worse by spreading it across different files).

Comment: If you're unwilling to refactor your code to functions etc., put those variables in e.g. `common_variables.py` and import them from there (with `from common_variables import *` if you must).

Comment: But how will `import` do the looping?

Comment: It won't. You'd loop externally as in my answer, but you were concerned about the maintainability; moving the configuration variables to one file you can import them from alleviates that.

Comment: I think you missed one of the points of my question: adding another file does not make my scripts more maintainable - quite the contrary. I am trying to keep everything in one file. Also, I am not "unwilling" to refactor - it's just that using a function creates a need to add each new loop variable in three extra places (apart from setting the range: adding that range to the loop range, passing it to the function, adding it to the function header). This is overhead I'd like to skip.

Comment: I misunderstood your comment, then; I had understood your script consists of multiple modules.

Comment: @bers I added another approach which is in-file and still somewhat non-obtrusive.

Answer (score 0):

In so many words, anything you want to reuse should be modularized. The first level of that is to create a function. (In more complex cases, you might want to put it in a separate file, and/or create a class with several methods.)

You want to *encapsulate* the internals (whatever goes inside the function) but *expose* the parameters which the caller should have control over. Concretely, your function should accept as arguments anything which should be controlled by an external variable or constant.

(If you want to create additional wrapper functions which hard-code a set of arguments, that's fine, but mere convenience.)

```py
INPUT_FILE = "data.csv"
MIN_SIZE = 35
MAX_SIZE = 70

def pipeline(n_comp, min_size, max_size, input_file):
  output_file = f"plot_{n_comp}.pdf"

  data = read(input_file)
  results = process(data, n_comp)
  figure = plot(results, min_size, max_size)
  store(figure, output_file)

for N_COMP in (3, 5, 7, 9, 11):
  pipeline(N_COMP, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE, INPUT_FILE)
```

Optionally, you might declare default values for some of the parameters.

```py
def pipeline(n_comp, input_file, min_size=MIN_SIZE, max_size=MAX_SIZE):
```

You could call this with `pipeline(3, "data.csv")` and the function would fall back to the defaults for the arguments you did not supply. The optional arguments have to be last, so I had to reorder them here.

Answer (score 0):

This `autoloop.py` serves my purpose well:

````
"""
Upon import, read and execute initial script for autoloop parameter combinations.

Example code:
```
import autoloop

X = autoloop.looptuple(1, 2)
Y = autoloop.looprange(10, 12)
print(X, Y)
```
"""
import itertools
import os
import re
import sys


def noloop():
    """Make pylint happy."""


def loopdummy(*args):
    """Return first element in case we are not looping."""
    return args[0] if args else None


looptuple = loopdummy
looprange = loopdummy


def find_vars(script, looptype):
    """Parse var = autoloop.looptype(value1, value2, ...) lines."""
    pattern = fr"(?P<var>[^\W0-9]\w*)\s*=\s*autoloop\.loop{looptype}\((?P<values>.+)\)"
    matches = [match for line in script if (match := re.fullmatch(pattern, line))]
    variables = [match.group("var") for match in matches]
    value_lists = [re.split(r"\s*,\s*", match.group("values")) for match in matches]

    if looptype == "range":
        value_lists = [range(*map(int, values)) for values in value_lists]

    return (variables, value_lists)


def loop():
    """See module docstring."""
    if sys.argv[0] == __file__:
        return

    with open(sys.argv[0]) as script_file:
        script = script_file.read().splitlines()

    if "autoloop.noloop()" in script:
        return

    (tuple_vars, tuple_value_lists) = find_vars(script, "tuple")
    (range_vars, range_value_lists) = find_vars(script, "range")

    variables = tuple_vars + range_vars
    value_lists = tuple_value_lists + range_value_lists

    # if not variables:
    #     return

    script = [line for line in script if "autoloop" not in line]
    for values in itertools.product(*value_lists):
        preamble = [f"{var} = {value}" for (var, value) in zip(variables, values)]
        print("Exec'ing with", ", ".join(preamble), "...")
        new_script = "\n".join(itertools.chain(preamble, script))
        exec(new_script, locals(), locals())  # pylint: disable=exec-used
    print("Done.")
    os._exit(0)  # pylint: disable=protected-access


loop()
````

To use it,

- add `import autoloop` (which doesn't do anything, yet)
- convert at least one constant, e.g. `X = 1` to `X = autoloop.looptuple(1, 2, 3)`

To pause it,

- add `autoloop.noloop()` anywhere in the code (it will use the first value from the `looptuple`/`looprange`)

The example code prints:

```
Exec'ing with X = 1, Y = 10 ...
1 10
Exec'ing with X = 1, Y = 11 ...
1 11
Exec'ing with X = 2, Y = 10 ...
2 10
Exec'ing with X = 2, Y = 11 ...
2 11
Done.
```

This is missing a bazillion of checks. It currently adds variables to the top rather than where they should be defined, so dependencies won't work properly. It won't work when you import `autoloop` in a file which was itself imported. Parsing is minimal at best. But for my small examples, it is working fine.